# Display Id value in contact form 7

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

I need help.
I have the code below : the script returns the id of each button.

After that, I need to return the selected id value in a form generated by contact form 7 in Wordpress.

In my situation, each button opens a modal with a form. 
But I can't return the id in the form...

```js
function getId(myId)
{
document.getElementById("recupTitle").textContent = myId.id;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><button id="1" onclick="getId(this);">Click the button 1</button></li>
<li><button id="2" onclick="getId(this);">Click the button 2</button></li>
<li><button id="3" onclick="getId(this);">Click the button 3</button></li>
<li><button id="4" onclick="getId(this);">Click the button 4</button></li>
<li><button id="5" onclick="getId(this);">Click the button 5</button></li>
</ul>

<p id="recupTitle"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On click also set the form value with the id

```
document.getElementById("myField").value = myId.id;
```

Comment: there is my form : Name* [text* your-name] 
Email* [email* your-email]
[submit "S'inscrire"] How can I integrate the value ?

Comment: [contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/) Take a look here

Comment: Yes, I already use this extension but I found nothing about javascript value. I tried [dynamictext dynamicname 'myField'] but returns MyField, not the value

Comment: Ok, sorry... It works now. I insert [dynamictext Title id:myField "'myField'"] in my form. Thanks you for the help !

Comment: You did the job I just gave you hints :)